# Textbooks for PDE after Folland

Tags: partial-differential-equations, education

I am a student who has just finished Folland's nice book Introduction to Partial Differential Equations. And I also read L. Craig Evan's textbook before.
Could any expert here suggest a PDE book in the level above those two ones, for example, like some introductory textbooks for non-linear PDE or some complementary readings?

Comment: I am not an expert. But I think that the answer depends on what you want to do: you cannot read the whole bibliography on PDE! Choose an argument to study and research instead of a book to read.

Comment: If you simply like reading books about PDE and want to spend more time doing what you like, I suggest multivolume series by Taylor and Hörmander. They'll keep you occupied for a while.

Comment: John had a nice short book, and Garabedian has a longer one - these are less modern, but they're excellent. For elliptic PDE, I would recommend taking a look at Han and Lin's book, and there's also the Ladyzhenskaya and Uraltseva books (apologies for mangling the spelling).